# How to make a table view common for multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make multiple view controllers with a common table view but i am not able to this i have made a view file and added table view in and importing that file to all view controllers but not able to get the same table view every

here is code :

```
//
//  LeftTableViewClass.h
// 
//
//  Created by   on 30/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014   All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LeftTableViewClass : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

---

```
//
//  LeftTableViewClass.m
// 
//
//  Created by  on 30/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014   All rights reserved.
//

#import "LeftTableViewClass.h"

@implementation LeftTableViewClass

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 4;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    //cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";


    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

---

```
LeftTableViewClass *leftTableViewClass = [[LeftTableViewClass alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:leftTableViewClass];
```

Comment: What do you mean by common are you wanting same table in two VCs?

Comment: Just have 1 view controller with a table view. You then just create different instances of the view controller with different dataSource/delegates

Comment: @CW0007007, is right. It's all a game of `delegate`s and `dataSource`s.

Comment: It's a good idea to practice this as your view controllers should NEVER be the dataSources of anything. In my opinion anyway.

Comment: @CW0007007 help me with some code plz

Comment: [leftTableViewClass setDataSource:ANOTHER_CLASS];

Comment: it is only for showing ? or edit also performed?

Comment: @iDev it is for only showing.

Comment: @CW0007007 another class is not working :(

Comment: then how about actions in `didSelectRow:`

Comment: Have you just copy and pasted that ? You need to replace ANOTHER_CLASS with what ever NSObject is acting as the dataSource..

Answer (score 0):

You can a make a table view class and initialise(alloc) it once and keep the reference for all the controllers.

Comment: So my question is are you using the same instance "leftTableViewClass" for every controller?

Comment: yes i am using and the view is displaying on every controller but table view delegates are not able to common for every controller. I have to repeat on every controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake you are making here is you think you need to subclass UITableView to define it's behavior. But instead Apple uses a delegate design pattern here.  Any UITableView has two properties we should worry about here. `delegate` and `dataSource`.

The delegate pattern is when the object delegates certain actions to other objects. In this case you set the UITableView's `delegate` and `datasource` properties to the object that will define it's behaviors.  `delegate` tells the table view what to do when an action is taken (like selecting a cell). `dataSource` is used when to tell how many cells and what kind there are.

In your case, you can subclass (although this isn't strictly necessary) but you never set your `dataSource` and `delegate` for your table view. You can do this in your init method if you like.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This now tells the table view to use itself as the delegate and dataSource. See this article for more information on UITableView [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html).

Comment: I have to use cellForRowAtIndexPath at every view controller . Tell me one place to keep it please.

Comment: Just create an object that implements `UITableViewDataSource` and set any table view's `dataSource` to that object. You can roll this all into a UITableView subclass, just use the init function above and use that for your table view.  Or read through Apple's documentation, they explain it all there. Come back with any specific questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `UIView` subclass with a costructor method which collects ***the datasource data [array] and frame value*** then inside the class include the code for table with reference to the frame size of view and display it whereever you want it by creating an instance and adding as a subview.

**Why your current option doesn't work**

Didn't provide the frame of the `LeftTableViewClass` instance you created.
The frame is the key to add the subviews.Make the instance allocation using `initWithFrame` method

Use

```
LeftTableViewClass *leftTableViewClass = [[LeftTableViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 200)];
```

Comment: I have to use cellForRowAtIndexPath at every view controller . Tell me one place to keep it please. –

Comment: nope..in the uiview class write the datasource methods and delegates